# how to randomly initialize weights in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow

in tensorflow, I learned from the tutorial that one would initialize the variables with something like

`sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())`

however I found that every time I run this with the same input dataset, the loss value starts with the same value.

I presume this is due to the fact that the initialization is always setting up the variables with the same values. (probably zero)

I wish to randomize the values of weights. I've tried searching for this but  tensorflow docs doesn't give a clear answer if the initialization is done with zero values by default or random values.

How can I specify the initializaing to setup random values?

---

**update**

my network is first a bunch of CNNs and pooling layers like below:
```
conv1 = tf.layers.conv2d(inputs=input_layer, filters=32, kernel_size=[3,3], padding="same", activation=tf.nn.relu, name="conv_chad_1")

```
    pool1 = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(inputs=conv1,pool_size=[2,2],strides=2)

    conv2 = tf.layers.conv2d(inputs=pool1, filters=64, kernel_size=[3,3], padding="same", activation=tf.nn.relu, name="conv_chad_2")

    pool2 = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(inputs=conv2,pool_size=[2,2],strides=2, name="pool_chad_2")
```

```

AFAIK, the weights are defined inside these predefined layers. How do I specify these layers to initialize their weight variables randomly??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should provide more information. For example, how do you initialize your variables in your graph? For initializing your weights in a neural network, you must initialize them randomly (biases are ok to be initialized all as zero). Thus you must use a code like the following for defining them with proper initialization:

```
# initialize weights randomly from a Gaussian distribution
# step 1: create the initializer for weights
weight_initer = tf.truncated_normal_initializer(mean=0.0, stddev=0.01)
# step 2: create the weight variable with proper initialization
W = tf.get_variable(name="Weight", dtype=tf.float32, shape=[784, 200], initializer=weight_initer)

# initialize biases as zero
# step 1: create the initializer for biases
bias_initer =tf.constant(0., shape=[200], dtype=tf.float32)
# step 2: create the bias variable with proper initialization
b = tf.get_variable(name="Bias", dtype=tf.float32, initializer=bias_initer)
```

Comment: I have updated my question. In my code, most of the network consists of layers. Do you know how to command the layers to initialize their weights with random values?

Comment: Yes, try initializing your layers like this:  `conv2=tf.layers.conv2d(inputs=pool1, filters=64, kernel_size=[3,3],                         kernel_initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer(), bias_initializer=tf.zeros_initializer(), padding="same", activation=tf.nn.relu, name="conv_chad_2")`.  This will initialize your weights randomly from a Gaussian distribution with a variance related to the variance of its outputs (Xavier method) and biases as zeros.

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem, it's like you are executing the line of code that is global_value_initializer() every time. What you need to do is this, for instance, if you're working on jupyter notebook then declare that part of session(declaring init) in one cell and rest of them in another cell(training part).

Also, for when you want to continue training model after some pause you might wanna save the parameters and restore them. How to do that ,you can look [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/saved_model). If that doesn't solve your problem then show me that part of code you're dealing with. I might be able to help more.

---

---

**PS:** You can't restore your parameters when you change your optimizer, you gotta stick with one as far as I know. you can't do 100 iterations with one optimzer, and continue with another optimizer with those same parameters. Or maybe you can try some hack that might let you do that, let me know too.

Comment: sorry but no the answer that I am looking for. I now how to save and restore the model.
I have tried starting a training session without loading any previous progresses. But a few dozen of this kind of attempts, I noticed that the loss values all start from the same value. This lead me to think that my layers are all zero initialized by default. I wish this to initialize with random values.

Comment: you can try tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer and full documentation [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/layers/xavier_initializer) as for how to use it , place initializer as weights_initializer shown [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/layers/conv2d) lemme know if that works.